# Parse the json value and get ID into var in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have list of company names with IDs. I have used a drop down and showing company name in it by parsing JSON data. uncertainly I am unable to get the ID of the selected item in the drop down menu.

My json data is

```
{
"success": true,
"message": [
    {
        "company_name": "ABC",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "company_name": "JHG",
        "id": 10
    }
]}
```

My swift code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: COMPANY_URL)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as?URL)!, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) ->
        Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
        {

           // print(jsonObj.value(forKey: "message")!)


            if let messageArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "message") as? NSArray
            {
                for message in messageArray
                {
                    if let messageDict = message as? NSDictionary
                    {

                        if let data = data {


                            let successmessage = jsonObj.value(forKey: "success") as? Int

                            if(successmessage == 1)
                            {

                                if let company_name = messageDict.value(forKey: "company_name")
                                {
                                    self.companiesArray.append(company_name as! String)
                                }
                                if let company_id = messageDict.value(forKey: "id")
                                {

                                    self.companyidstr.append(company_id as! Int)

                                    print(self.companyidstr)
                                }

                                for messageArray in self.companyidstr
                                {
                                    print(messageArray)

                                    let btnlabel = Int(self.companyBtn.titleLabel!.text!)

                                    if(btnlabel == Int(messageArray))
                                    {
                                        self.companyidstring = messageArray
                                        print(self.companyidstring)
                                               // THIS IS WHERE IT NEED TO SHOW ID BUT NOT                            }
                                }



                                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                })




                            } else
                            {

                            }

                        }


                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }).resume()
```

My requirement is to show list of company name's to users but when they select any company name,should save in the form of concerned ID of the selected item.

my ENTIRE CODE:

```
class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var companyBtn: UIButton!


    final let COMPANY_URL = COMPANY_URL

    var companiesArray = [String]()

    var companyidstr = [Int]()

    var companyidstring: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadCompanyNamesFromDB()
        // insertUserDetailsintoDB()
        tableView.isHidden = true
        self.downloadCompanyNamesFromDB()
        //tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func companyBtnClick(_ sender: Any) {
        // tableView.isHidden = false

        if(tableView.isHidden)
        {
            animate(toogle: true)

        } else
        {
            animate(toogle: false)
        }


    }

    func animate(toogle: Bool)
    {
        if(toogle)
        {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3)
            {
                self.tableView.isHidden = false
            }
        } else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3)
            {
                self.tableView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return companiesArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = companiesArray[indexPath.row] 
        print(companiesArray)
        return cell
    }        

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let companytitle = companiesArray[indexPath.row]
        companyBtn.setTitle(companytitle, for: .normal)
        print(companytitle)
       // print(companiesArray[indexPath.row].id as! String)
       // companiesArray = message   --> HERE IS THE CODE
        animate(toogle: false)
    }

    func downloadCompanyNamesFromDB()
    {    

        let url = NSURL(string: COMPANY_URL)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as?URL)!, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) ->
            Void in


            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary
            {

                // print(jsonObj.value(forKey: "message")!)

                if let messageArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "message") as? NSArray
                {
                    for message in messageArray
                    {
                        if let messageDict = message as? NSDictionary
                        {

                            if let data = data {                                    

                                let successmessage = jsonObj.value(forKey: "success") as? Int

                                if(successmessage == 1)
                                {


                                } else
                                {

                                }                                    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }).resume()
    }       

    } 
}
```

Comment: you can make use of `didSelectRowAt` and `print(arr[indexPath.row].id)` where `arr = message`

Comment: @Sh_Khan  i am getting an error saying "Value of type 'String' has no member 'id'"

Comment: how this occurs share code

Comment: @Sh_Khan see the edit

Answer (score 0):

It's better to

```
let dec = JSONDecoder()
dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let res = try! dec.decode(Root.self,from:data)
print(res.message)
```

---

```
// MARK: - Empty
struct Root: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let message: [Message]
}

// MARK: - Message
struct Message: Codable {
    let companyName: String
    let id: Int
}
```

---

```
var companiesArray = [Message]() 

let url = URL(string: COMPANY_URL)!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) ->
    Void in 
    guard let data = data else { return } 
    let dec = JSONDecoder()
    dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let res = try! dec.decode(Root.self,from:data)
    companiesArray = res.message
    print(res.message)

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

}).resume()
```

Comment: where should i insert JSONDecoder() code? inside the for loop or  inside if(successmessage == 1) condition?

Comment: it is printing the companies names with id but my drop down is not working after this

Comment: @Manognya change array as in edit `var companiesArray = [Message]() `